# What is the simplest way to rewrite Postman requests to C#

Tags: c#, api-testing, rest-api, json, postman

I have made lots of made Requests in `JSON` in `Postman`.

Now I am thinking about re-write all the `Postman-tests` into `C#`.

There are many different `Nuget` packages that could be used.

**I have googled a lots, but the picture I got that:**

everyone is doing it in their own way, though many people is using `Resharper` is that simple?

I want to keep it as simple as possible, because I am very new to C#.

**Any suggestions tips of how to do this? (Guides/tutorials?).**

Answer (score 4):

[ReSharper](https://jetbrains.com/resharper/) is an Visual Studio [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) Plugin for C# by JetBrains. This won't help you much unless you want to write everything from scratch.

Postman has the ability to [generate code snippets](https://getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets) for various languages and frameworks, including C# (using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) as REST/HTTP client). Consequently, you should be able to simply "convert" your requests to C#. (Haven't tried this myself, so I can't tell how good that generated code is.)

Comment: I did this ,But when i copy and past and import rest dlls, Im not getting the response.